# PowerShell Regex Help needed for a Get-Content

Tags: regex, powershell

I use `Get-Content` to pull text over from a txt file.
Example of some of the text would be:

```
projectName - url (Automation Complete)
otherProject - url (Task Complete)
```

I am attempting to store the count of how many times each project would have an Automation or Task Complete and print out.

This is what I kind of have so far:

```
$serviceProjClosedTasksCount = (Select-String -InputObject $wsr -Pattern "(Task Complete)","Service [Pp]roj" -AllMatches).Matches.Count
```

Comment: `-Pattern "(Service [Pp]roj)|(Task Complete)"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you don't want to count "Automation Complete" and "Task Complete" separately per project I'd probably do something like this:

```
$wsr -match '\((Automation|Task) Complete\)' |
    Group-Object { ($_ -split '\s+-\s+')[0] } -NoElement |
    Select-Object Name, Count
```

If you want automations and task separately per project, something like this might do:

```
$wsr -match '\((Automation|Task) Complete\)' |
    Group-Object { $_ -replace '^(.*?) - .*\((Automation|Task) Complete\).*', '$1 $2' } -NoElement |
    Select-Object Name, Count
```

Comment: If you're only interested in name and count, you can include the -NoElement switch which removes the collection of objects.

Comment: @MikeShepard Indeed. For some reason I keep forgetting about that parameter. Thanks for reminding me.

Comment: First thank you for Assisting me, this is close to what I am looking for.

Each line in this txt is an individual task I am just trying to see how many Automation Items I have for ProjectA and how many Task Items for ProjectA I have as well.
<br />
Example:<br />
`code`
ProjectA - url (Automation Complete)
ProjectA - url (Task Complete)
ProjectA - url (Task Complete)
ProjectB - url (Automation Complete) `code`

Comment: Sorry for the non legible comment above. Example would end up having
ProjectA Automation 1    |        
ProjectA Tasks 2    |
ProjectB Automation 1   |